# pandas split values in column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to pandas (version 1.1.5) and have tried `str.split()` and `str.extract()` to split column `POS` of numerical values with no success. My dataframe is about 3000 lines and is structured like this (note `_` and `-` delimiters in subset):

```
df.head()

      SAMPLE CHROM        POS REF ALT
1  Sample1     7    105121514       C       T
2  Sample2    17    7359940         C       A
3  Sample3     X    76777781        A       G
4  Sample4    16    70531965-70531965       C       G
5  Sample5     6    26093141-26093141       G       A
6  Sample6    12    11905465        C       T
7  Sample7     4    103527484_103527848       G       A
```

I would like for the dataframe to look like this (i.e. retain values preceding all delimiters):

```
      SAMPLE CHROM        POS REF ALT
1  Sample1     7    105121514       C       T
2  Sample2    17    7359940         C       A
3  Sample3     X    76777781        A       G
4  Sample4    16    70531965        C       G
5  Sample5     6    26093141        G       A
6  Sample6    12    11905465        C       T
7  Sample7     4    103527484       G       A
```

My attempts have either split the rows only containing a delimiter and dropping all other rows, dropping all rows containing just the delimiters, or dropping all values.

For example, `df['POS'] = df['POS'].str.replace(r'[-|_]\d+', '')` outputs:

```
      SAMPLE CHROM  POS REF ALT
1  Sample1     7    NaN   C   T
2  Sample2    17    NaN   C   A
3  Sample3     X    NaN   A   G
4  Sample4    16    NaN   C   G
5  Sample5     6    NaN   G   A
6  Sample6    12    NaN   C   T
7  Sample7     4    NaN   G   A
```

---

Accepting the solution from @PaulS below as I needed to convert the column datatype from object to string first in order for `str.replace()` to work!

```
df.dtypes

SAMPLE    object
CHROM     object
POS       object
REF       object
ALT       object
dtype: object

df['POS'] = df['POS'].astype('str')
df['POS'] = df['POS'].str.replace(r'[-|_]\d+', '')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution, based on the idea of replacing all characters after `_` or `-` (inclusive) with the empty string (`''`):

```
df['POS'] = df['POS'].str.replace(r'[-_]\d+', '')
```

Output:

```
  CHROM        POS REF ALT
0     7  105121514   C   T
1    17    7359940   C   A
2     X   76777781   A   G
3    16   70531965   C   G
4     6   26093141   G   A
5    12   11905465   C   T
6     4  103527484   G   A
```

Comment: When I apply `df['POS'] = df['POS'].str.replace(r'[-|_]\d+', '')`, only the values before the `-` or `_` are kept, while all other values with no delimiters are dropped. I'm stumped.

Comment: Strange, @eb0906. Please, post your `df.head()`.

Comment: After having switched off my computer, it also occurred to me that the problem might be to have `POS` column with values of mixed type (numeric and character). Fortunately, you also spotted that, @eb0906.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most popular solution, but you can try.

```
df.POS = df.POS.str.replace("-", " ")
df.POS = df.POS.str.replace("_", " ")
df.POS = df.POS.str.split()
df.POS = [x[0] for x in df.POS]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on pandas >= 1.4, you can use a regex with `str.split()`. Combine this with `expand=True` and then just take the first result and I think you've got what you need.

```py
df['POS'] = df['POS'].str.split('[-_]',expand=True,regex=True)[0]
```